# Add dropout layers between pretrained dense layers in keras

Tags: python, keras

In `keras.applications`, there is a VGG16 model pre-trained on imagenet.

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')
```

This model has the following structure.

```
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 3, 224, 224)   0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Convolution2D)     (None, 64, 224, 224)  1792        input_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Convolution2D)     (None, 64, 224, 224)  36928       block1_conv1[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 64, 112, 112)  0           block1_conv2[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Convolution2D)     (None, 128, 112, 112) 73856       block1_pool[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Convolution2D)     (None, 128, 112, 112) 147584      block2_conv1[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 128, 56, 56)   0           block2_conv2[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Convolution2D)     (None, 256, 56, 56)   295168      block2_pool[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Convolution2D)     (None, 256, 56, 56)   590080      block3_conv1[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Convolution2D)     (None, 256, 56, 56)   590080      block3_conv2[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 256, 28, 28)   0           block3_conv3[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Convolution2D)     (None, 512, 28, 28)   1180160     block3_pool[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Convolution2D)     (None, 512, 28, 28)   2359808     block4_conv1[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Convolution2D)     (None, 512, 28, 28)   2359808     block4_conv2[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 512, 14, 14)   0           block4_conv3[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Convolution2D)     (None, 512, 14, 14)   2359808     block4_pool[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Convolution2D)     (None, 512, 14, 14)   2359808     block5_conv1[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Convolution2D)     (None, 512, 14, 14)   2359808     block5_conv2[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 512, 7, 7)     0           block5_conv3[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)                (None, 25088)         0           block5_pool[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                      (None, 4096)          102764544   flatten[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                      (None, 4096)          16781312    fc1[0][0]                        
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)              (None, 1000)          4097000     fc2[0][0]                        
====================================================================================================
Total params: 138,357,544
Trainable params: 138,357,544
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I would like to fine-tune this model with dropout layers between the dense layers (fc1, fc2 and predictions), while keeping all the pre-trained weights of the model intact. I know it's possible to access each layer individually with `model.layers`, but I haven't found anywhere how to add new layers between the existing layers.

What's the best practice of doing this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I found an answer myself by using [Keras functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/)

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.models import Model

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')

# Store the fully connected layers
fc1 = model.layers[-3]
fc2 = model.layers[-2]
predictions = model.layers[-1]

# Create the dropout layers
dropout1 = Dropout(0.85)
dropout2 = Dropout(0.85)

# Reconnect the layers
x = dropout1(fc1.output)
x = fc2(x)
x = dropout2(x)
predictors = predictions(x)

# Create a new model
model2 = Model(input=model.input, output=predictors)
```

`model2` has the dropout layers as I wanted

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 3, 224, 224)   0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Convolution2D)     (None, 64, 224, 224)  1792        input_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Convolution2D)     (None, 64, 224, 224)  36928       block1_conv1[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 64, 112, 112)  0           block1_conv2[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Convolution2D)     (None, 128, 112, 112) 73856       block1_pool[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Convolution2D)     (None, 128, 112, 112) 147584      block2_conv1[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 128, 56, 56)   0           block2_conv2[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Convolution2D)     (None, 256, 56, 56)   295168      block2_pool[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Convolution2D)     (None, 256, 56, 56)   590080      block3_conv1[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Convolution2D)     (None, 256, 56, 56)   590080      block3_conv2[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 256, 28, 28)   0           block3_conv3[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Convolution2D)     (None, 512, 28, 28)   1180160     block3_pool[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Convolution2D)     (None, 512, 28, 28)   2359808     block4_conv1[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Convolution2D)     (None, 512, 28, 28)   2359808     block4_conv2[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 512, 14, 14)   0           block4_conv3[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Convolution2D)     (None, 512, 14, 14)   2359808     block4_pool[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Convolution2D)     (None, 512, 14, 14)   2359808     block5_conv1[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Convolution2D)     (None, 512, 14, 14)   2359808     block5_conv2[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 512, 7, 7)     0           block5_conv3[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)                (None, 25088)         0           block5_pool[0][0]                
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                      (None, 4096)          102764544   flatten[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)              (None, 4096)          0           fc1[0][0]                        
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                      (None, 4096)          16781312    dropout_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)              (None, 4096)          0           fc2[1][0]                        
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)              (None, 1000)          4097000     dropout_2[0][0]                  
====================================================================================================
Total params: 138,357,544
Trainable params: 138,357,544
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: How to add BatchNormalization with in this functional API?

Comment: @Malathi It was a while ago I worked on Keras last time, but I believe it should be similar. Make sure the initial parameters of the batch normalization has mean 0 and std 1 (I'm not sure if this is the default in Keras). If you have problems you can always ask a new question and hopefully someone more updated than me can answer you.

Comment: How would your solution to this problem look like if you were using Keras Sequential API?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that stays within the Keras "Sequential API".

You can loop through the layers and sequentially add them to an updated Sequential model. Add Dropouts after the layers of your choice with an if-clause.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')

# check structure and layer names before looping
model.summary()

# loop through layers, add Dropout after layers 'fc1' and 'fc2'
updated_model = Sequential()
for layer in model.layers:
    updated_model.add(layer)
    if layer.name in ['fc1', 'fc2']:
        updated_model.add(Dropout(.2))

model = updated_model

# check structure
model.summary()
```

Comment: When I test your approach, I get the same prediction every time.  Can you please verify your answer?

Comment: @random9 Will get on that. Can you clarify the issue more. You are getting the same prediction every time when you predict with the pre-trained model? That should be expected as the weights are not changing and there is (AFAIK) no stochastic element in the prediction operations. The sequential model automatically only applies dropout when the model is training, so there should be no random dropping of nodes during prediction (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787011/how-to-disable-dropout-while-prediction-in-keras).

Comment: Sorry, I was net precise enough. What I meant was that the output activations are exactly the same. But there should be small differences between each prediction.

Comment: @random9 Thanks for clarifying. Why should the final layer activations be different when predicting multiple times on the same example? Is this something you find when making predictions with the unmodified VGG-16 model?

Comment: The dropout process should inject some randomness into the network. Therefore I expect slightly different output activations.

Comment: @random9 The dropping of nodes only occurs during the training process (see the link I shared earlier). So during the prediction forward pass, the network behaves like a normal feedforward (or conv, etc) network with no random operations. (see for additional ref: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#add_dropout)

Comment: This answer strictly assumes that the model is a "linked-list", not an arbitrary DAG