# How Can I Add drop out technique to the keras Retina net?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, dropout

I'm working with RetinaNet NN model for object detection and I faced with over fitting problem.
One of the solutions is adding "Dropout".
I'm Using the keras code [Here](https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet)

I want to Add Dropout to the last layers but I don't know how to add.

Can anyone help which file should I change?and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while, I tried many solutions but non of them didn't say how to add exactly, so I tried and then found how to add, So decided to answer it myself!

Just need to add a line like this:

`outputs = keras.layers.SpatialDropout1D (rate=dropout_rate) (outputs)`

You can use another layer dropout type like :
`SpatialDropout2D` and more.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to store the fully connected layer into a variable like:

```
fc1 = model.layers[-3]
fc2 = model.layers[-2]
predictions = model.layers[-1]
```

Then create your dropout layer and reconnect them all to build a new Model as shown in this post :[Add dropout layers between pretrained dense layers in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475381/add-dropout-layers-between-pretrained-dense-layers-in-keras)

Hope this helps.