# Activate dropout in a pre-trained VGG16 model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Tensorflow 2.0 and a pre-trained VGG16 model and want to activate dropout during prediction. So far I tried the following without success:

```
model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet', is_training=True)

model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet', dropout_rate=0.5)
```

However, none of these approaches worked. How can I enable dropout during the prediction phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VGG16 architecture does not contain a dropout layer by default. You would need to insert a dropout layer in the model.

Here is a post I found useful to solve this:
[Add dropout layers between pretrained dense layers in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475381/add-dropout-layers-between-pretrained-dense-layers-in-keras)

Comment: I don't know how applicable the solution is given that the TensorFlow libraries have been updated quite a bit in the meantime!