# How to make input layer explicit in tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475381/add-dropout-layers-between-pretrained-dense-layers-in-keras) makes use of a pre-trained VGG network, whose summary shows an `InputLayer` being used. I like the clarity of the explicit input layer... even if functionally it does nothing (true?). But when I try to mimic this with something like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(128, 128, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
```

the result displayed using `print(model.summary())` is no different from:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 3))
```

... and both show the first layer as being a `Conv2D` layer. Where did my `Input` layer go? And is it worth the hassle of getting it back?

Comment: I suspect it is just semantics, your input isn't really a layer. It is a tensor, the first layer is the Conv2D.

Comment: I suspect that too. But I'd like to know how to get it to show up from `model.summary()`. For that matter, I'd like to know where the `Connected To` column in the summary disappeared to as well - neither are there for me as they are in that question :-(

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input

Comment: The summary shows the layer, with it's input shape. The input is a tensor it isn't a layer. I don't get what you expect the summary to show. To me it has all of the information, but maybe it doesn't work in a more complicated example? edit: I checked the other one, I see a bit better what you're saying. Have you looked at what their actual input layer is?

Comment: I am too new to the environment to know how to check what their "actual input layer" is. All I can see is that the summary in that question shows it explicitly, but the above code does not show it... and the `Input` doc page you referenced shines no light on why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you're using a Sequential, try using a `keras.models.Model`.

```
inp = keras.layers.Input((128, 128, 3))
op = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(inp)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[ inp ], outputs = [op] )
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 128, 128, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 126, 126, 32)      896       
=================================================================
Total params: 896
Trainable params: 896
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: OK - so... at a guess... it was functionality that was so pointless nobody thought it necessary to implement it in `Sequential`? Likewise... is the "Connected To" column absent in your summary, but present in that question, also essentially pointless? Just trying to use some of these Q&A examples as benchmarks to try to reproduce...

Comment: @omatai If you look at your example, model.input is different and reflects that one was created via model.Input versus using input on you conv2D, also model.layers doesn't include the input layer with a sequential. Which I think is more substantial than the summary missing it. I think you're right to ask the questions, unfortunately some of the answers are : keras/tensorflow decide to change the api without documenting it.

Comment: For connected to: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6286

Answer (score 0):

No, you can keep them separate, it does not make any difference.

As for the `input_shape`, that argument can be specified for each and every layer, yet Keras is smart enough to deduce on its own the shape of the next layers so we do not mention it explicitly.

Comment: If they can be kept separate, can you provide a code snip that leads to `model.summary()` showing an `Input` layer?

Comment: Like in the accepted answer, by using the Functional API